# What should you do after changeing thousands of URLs?

Tags: url

I currently changed 50,000+ URLs of my website something similar to `example.com/articles/new-slug` from `example.com/old-slug`.

What I have done so far.

1. Add 301 redirection for all old articles to new one.
2. Remove old sitemap from Google Web Master Tools and Add new sitemap.

What else should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you have only changed the URLs (not the content or metas), it looks like you are on the right track. I would also ensure that you request a re crawl in Google webmaster tools to ensure the new URLs are indexed as quickly as possible.

Comment: Thanks. Content and meta also changed little bit..Then?